# Skip reading a line in a INI file if its length greater than n in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, ini, getline

I want to skip reading a line in the INI file if has more than 1000 characters.This is the code i'm using:

```
#define MAX_LINE 1000
char buf[MAX_LINE];
CString strTemp;
str.Empty();
for(;;)
{
    is.getline(buf,MAX_LINE);
    strTemp=buf;
    if(strTemp.IsEmpty()) break;
    str+=strTemp;

    if(str.Find("^")>-1)
    {
        str=str.Left( str.Find("^") );
        do
        {
            is.get(buf,2);
        } while(is.gcount()>0);
        is.getline(buf,2);
    }
    else if(strTemp.GetLength()!=MAX_LINE-1) break;

}
//is.getline(buf,MAX_LINE);
return is;
```

...

The problem i'm facing is that if the characters exceed 1000 if seems to fall in a infinite loop(unable to read next line).How can i make the getline to skip that line and read the next line??

Comment: Can you post a complete sample? What is 'is'?

Comment: Why would you want to skip the line?  Why are you not using `string` or `CString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const std::size_t max_line = 1000;  // not a macro, macros are disgusting

std::string line;
while (std::getline(is, line))
{
  if (line.length() > max_line)
    continue;
  // else process the line ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How abut checking the return value of `getline` and break if that fails?

..or if `is` is an istream, you could check for an eof() condition to break you out.

```
#define MAX_LINE 1000
char buf[MAX_LINE];
CString strTemp;
str.Empty();
while(is.eof() == false)
{
    is.getline(buf,MAX_LINE);
    strTemp=buf;
    if(strTemp.IsEmpty()) break;
    str+=strTemp;

    if(str.Find("^")>-1)
    {
        str=str.Left( str.Find("^") );
        do
        {
            is.get(buf,2);
        } while((is.gcount()>0) && (is.eof() == false));
        stillReading = is.getline(buf,2);
    }
    else if(strTemp.GetLength()!=MAX_LINE-1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
return is;
```

Answer (score 0):

For something completely different:

```
std::string strTemp;
str.Empty();
while(std::getline(is, strTemp)) { 
    if(strTemp.empty()) break;
    str+=strTemp.c_str(); //don't need .c_str() if str is also a std::string

    int pos = str.Find("^"); //extracted this for speed
    if(pos>-1){
        str=str.Left(pos);
        //Did not translate this part since it was buggy
    } else
        //not sure of the intent here either
        //it would stop reading if the line was less than 1000 characters.
}
return is;
```

This uses strings for ease of use, and no maximum limits on lines.  It also uses the `std::getline` for the dynamic/magic everything, but I did not translate the bit in the middle since it seemed very buggy to me, and I couldn't interpret the intent.

The part in the middle simply reads two characters at a time until it reaches the end of the file, and then everything after that would have done bizarre stuff since you weren't checking return values.  Since it was completely wrong, I didn't interpret it.